# print last 10 lines of file in c

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code in C, which will print the last ten lines of a file. But I dont know how to print the last lines. My code print only the first ten lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE * p;
  if(argc == 2){
    p=fopen(argv[argc-1], "r");
    if(p==NULL){
       fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Soubor se nenacetl.\n");
    return 1;
   }
}
else if (argc != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!\n");
    return 1;
}
char message[20][511],buffer[511];
int i=0;
int n=10;
while(fgets(buffer,511,p)){
    strcpy(message[i],buffer);
    printf("%s",message[i-n]);
    i++;
}
fclose(p);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should readline by line and keep the last ten lines in memory (preserve their order). When you reach the end of the file, you know the last lines and can print it. Alternatively you can read backwards in the file and try to find the lines by parsing the line endings. If the file is small enough, you can read it in completly, which makes backward parsing easier.

Comment: Add a second loop to print after you have read the file and stored the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You know this program will crash when you have more then 20 lines, right ?
Anyway, the easiest way without changing much is use the array as a kind of ring buffer, where i always points to the tail of the buffer:

```
(...)
char message[10][511],buffer[511];
int i=0;
while(fgets(buffer,511,p)){
    strcpy(message[i++],buffer);
    if (i>9) i=0;
}
fclose(p);
int n=0;
while(n<10) printf("%s",message[(i+n++)%10]);
return 0;
}
```